# @mui/lab/DateRangePicker - How to add custom toolbar with action buttons above and under calendar

Tags: material-ui, datepicker, daterangepicker

I'm using `DateRangePicker` from `@mui/lab` and now, there is need to add custom toolbar with action buttons above or under calendar (for example, buttons apply or cancel). I struggled to find solution but couldn't find something useful. It should be on both desktop and mobile versions of datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

For all those who suffer from the lack of simple and necessary solutions.
Hope this will help 
Here the [docs](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-range-picker/), but there is huge lack of information and examples

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} localeText={{ start: 'from', end: 'to' }}>
    <DateRangePicker
        components={{ //edit component
            PaperContent: data => { //exactly PaperContent
                const childCopy = [...data.children]; //duplicate to avoid errors
                const Component = () => <Box>BUILD YOUR COMPONENT</Box>;
                childCopy.push(<Component />);
                return childCopy; //return array of childrens
            }
        }}
        value={value}
        onChange={newValue => {
            setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
            <>
                <MNVTTextField {...startProps} />
                <Box>-</Box>
                <MNVTTextField {...endProps} />
            </>
        )}
    />
</LocalizationProvider>;
```